# angular schematics can't create .ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I created an Angular Schematics. There are two files in Files folder,fight.html and fight.ts  When I run schematics .: ng-add, terminal display create `fight.html` and `fight.ts`. And I publish it to npm.I'm on a new Angular Project run ng add packagename, the only `fight.html` are generated, no fight fight.ts

and [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8qoj7?file=src%2Fng-add%2Findex.ts) is my schematics stackblitz and my package name is new-schematics

Native angular version

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.6
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.800.6
@angular-devkit/core         8.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.0.6
@schematics/angular          8.0.6
@schematics/update           0.800.6
rxjs                         6.4.0
```

Comment: Hi CQ P, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider creating a [_Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help to track down the source of the issue.

Comment: @Edric Hi Edric,I provided the code above and I didn't know that Angular Schematics would work in the stackblitz

Comment: did you build the schematics before you published it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the content in `.npmignore` 
`*.ts=>.ts`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, I simply named my `.ts` files as `__typescript__` and then declared `__typescript__` in the template variables, so your file will be: `fight.__typescript__`

```
const templateSource = apply(url('./files'), [
  template({
    typescript: 'ts',
  }),
```

Comment: This is one way to do it, but I think it's easier to make the change in npmignore